# Link Conan packages over local repositories

Tags: artifactory, conan

Is there some way to link Conan packages over local repositories like Bintray (conan-center) ?

I read [Manipulating Artifacts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Manipulating+Artifacts) but I just found Copy and Move features.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory does not support linking artifacts between repositories.
As you mentioned, you can copy artifacts between repositories. Keep in mind that this is a "cheap copy" - since Artifactory is using a [checksum based storage](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Checksum-Based+Storage), the bytes are not duplicated and instead Artifactory just creates another pointer in the database.
Another option for having the same artifact in multiple repositories is using [virtual repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) (will be supported in the future for Conan). You can keep the artifact in a [local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories) and include this local repository in multiple virtual repositories. This will result with being able to access the same artifact from multiple virtual repositories.

Comment: Just beware of some current limitations for conan packages (only local repos are available so far, no virtual or remote repos). Also, some fix is needed to the copy feature, check https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2415

Comment: I agree @drodri, for now I need to create a local copy and upload to promote some package, as reported on issue. And when someone wants to promote a package, we dont have any review/request system, it's a pain create an issue manually just to review. Would be really nice to have same feature from Bintray, where a just button "Add to <repo>" reports a new request and any admin is able to review.